# How to write a program that diffs on hierarchy changes?

Tags: hierarchy, diff

Why is it that diff programs work on a line-by-line basis instead of a hierarchal one?

[All code can be expressed in a hierarchy](http://www.defmacro.org/ramblings/lisp.html), even though it's not immediately apparent.

Most of the data we work with is hierarchal as well.

What are the potential issues with building a piece of software that can diff based on hierarchy?

Comment: What are you going to use the diff for? Source control? Something else?

Comment: Ideally it could be used anywhere where two versions of the same file exist. Source control is a prime example of this. Being able to see the differences between two JSON responses in a typical REST response would be good as well.

Comment: I think you have the beginnings of a decent question, but it could use some work to build it up.  1) The article you link doesn't really draw the conclusion that "all code can be expressed in a hierarchy." That's your supposition from the article. 2) Are you asking "how to build" or are you asking "why don't diff's do XYZ"?  You've got two orthogonal questions there.  Please [edit] and focus on one question and consider moving the other aspect to its own question.  And please add some supporting research / effort on your part.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/3829587/120163

Answer (score 3):

1. Because usually, diffs are created to be able to compare any file, not only hierarchical-organized source code or data.
2. Because in order to obtain a tree from a source code, one needs to parse it first. Reading lines - every app can do that. Being able to parse C++, Ada, Java, COBOL, Haskell and [hundreds of programming languages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_programming_languages) and non-programming languages is not so easy.
3. Because showing some code as a tree will be extremely ugly. Imagine PHP code mixed with HTML with a deep hierarchy (including PHP code in HTML attributes).

But in some particular contexts when we are sure to have a limited set of languages, like Visual Studio, it would be nice to have a tree-based diff, indeed (as an option, with a choice between text-based and tree-based diff).